# Copied Code for a New Domain, Now in Browser Index File downloads as application/x-httpd-php

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Site not displaying but rather downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2137605/site-not-displaying-but-rather-downloading)

I copied the source code for a site, then installed it under a new domain.

Now, when I pull up the new domain in a browser, instead of pulling up the index file, the browser downloads a file.

In Firefox, the download pop-up says that I'm trying to download a "application/x-httpd-php".

The original site just loads the index file normally.  The file name is index.php.

Any idea why the new domain does this download?

**EDIT:**  I installed the domain on the same Plesk server where the original domain is.

Comment: Have you well configured your apache server?

Comment: Sounds like PHP isn't installed.  Is the source code actually dependent on domain?  I'm guessing no.  Likely duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2137605/567864 .

Comment: Which webserver are you using? Have you properly configured PHP for the virtual host of that domain? If so, what have you configured?

Comment: @ hakre I'm in Plesk.  How do I tell which webserver I'm on?

Comment: @John: contact support, they can tell you. Unless you don't know folks here can only guess. And if you ask support, directly ask them to fix it for you, should be the fastest way to get things done.

Answer (score 0):

If your web browser is receiving a response from the web server at application/x-httpd-php then we know that the mime type is configured correctly.

When a web server does not know how to handle a specific mime type it simply passes the data to the connecting client with the associated mime type in the header assuming that the user would know what to do with the data.

Your handlers need to be configured for the mime type application/x-httpd-php for the configuration being loaded for the new host.